# Cannot download metalink file - 404 error

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install ubuntu inside windows. I get this error:

```
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

The website address in the error is different to the actual URL - it should be

```
 ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.metalink
```

instead of

```
ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink
```

(with the `.2`). The second is present in the `.ini`. I tried editing `.ini` file to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean inside Windows?

Comment: The installation option selected is "ubuntu inside windows", which also means "alongside windows" (or so I presume - this option is for dual boot). Once this option is selected, rest of the installtion is from within windows and not the way mentioned in installation guidelines. Then installation (from windows - running pyrun.exe) aborts due to the above error

Comment: What ISO file did you download?

Comment: ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso --> This one is available in desktop downloads. Copied onto a bootable DVD as per instructions and then followed installation guidelines

Comment: Hmm seems you've done everything right. Could you try installing again?

Comment: Did at-least 10-15 times... same problem... tried editing .ini, tried copying .iso file in %temp% area, etc etc etc, can try one more time, do you think I can do something different?

Comment: What about via USB? Or redownload the iso and re burn?

Comment: will tryt to download

Comment: Got same error with ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso

Starting wubi.exe from Windows XP leads to the following error:
CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found